# Loopback alternative in JAVA

Tags: java, strongloop, loopback

Loopback is an awesome framework that offers a full REST API to all CRUD available operations with zero code.
It's a good thing to find such a framework that take care of all systematic operations but are there any alternative in java that recovers us from writing every single create, read, update, delete operation on every single model?

Answer (score 3):

[Spring Data Rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) is probably a safe candidate.

For CRUD operations on models, it's only a matter of writing an interface. This will define a rest endpoint and will take care automatically of the querying:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

Here's a nice tutorial that cover everything from the REST interface to the data storage:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

PS: Of course, java being java, there will be a bit more "ceremony", but Spring Boot project wizards (STS for Eclipse, or Intellij) will build your project skeleton in no time.